# Apache OpenJPA - Inserting tuple only if not exists in database

Tags: java, jpa, openjpa

Hello stackoverflow community.

I want to know, if there is a possibility in OpenJPA to check first if the object already exists in DB before inserting.

I have two clases:

```
imports...

@Entity(name="Player")
public class Player {
    private long id;
    private String nickName;
    private Team team; /* A Player is on a Team */

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "team_id")
    public Team getTeam() {
        return team;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /* more getters / setters ...*/
}
@Entity(name="Team")
public class Team {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private List<Player> players; /* A Team Has Players */

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "team", targetEntity = Player.class, 
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    public List<Player> getPlayers() {
        return players;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
```

If I want to add a new Player or Team, JPA should check first if this Player or Team is already in the database.
If yes, then it should use the primary / foreign key of existing unit.

Is this possible? Or do I need to write my own method?

Best Regards
Veote

Comment: JPA checks what is in the JPA spec clearly. If an object passed in to persist/merge is in detached/managed states then it is updated, otherwise it is created.

Comment: I think the problem here is, that I never want to update an existing tuple.

Comment: so you have to make a check on existence. JPA will not do it for you.

Comment: Ok thank you.
Then i have to do a lot of work :(
Many data, dependencies, etc.. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check this switch:
http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/2.2.0/apache-openjpa/docs/jpa_2.2.html#jpa_2.2_cascadePersist

I guess that you are using OpenJPA 2.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface EntityManager {
/**
* Make an instance managed and persistent.
* @param entity
* @throws EntityExistsException if the entity already exists.
* (If the entity already exists, the EntityExistsException may
* be thrown when the persist operation is invoked, or the
* EntityExistsException or another PersistenceException may be
* thrown at flush or commit time.)
* @throws IllegalArgumentException if the instance is not an
* entity
* @throws TransactionRequiredException if invoked on a
* container-managed entity manager of type
* PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION and there is
* no transaction
*/
public void persist(Object entity);
    . . . 
}
```

If you call EntityManager.persist(...) and pass in a Player instance that already exists in the DB, JPA(per the spec) will throw an EntityExistsException. I'd recommend reading through the [EntityManager javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html) to get a better feeling for what you can do with the API. Also, I'd recommend adding a @Version field to your Entities.

Comment: Hey,
that is what I do now. I first check if there is an Entity with same attributes as my object (without id). if yes -> take this Entity, if not persist my object

Answer (score -1):

Yes I think you can... http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.2.2/apache-openjpa-1.2.2/docs/manual/manual.html#ref_guide_integration_revmappingtool go this site for more details..

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i don't really find the solution for my problem :( Can you be more specific for my case? Is there a way without ant?